# SQL Modify Employee Shifts to Show Whole Schedule

Tags: sql

I am struggling how to approach this concept in SQL. I have the first layout as a return in SQL:

```
Emp   | Start |  End  | Option | 
Bob   | 7:30  | 16:00 | Shift  |
Bob   |10:15  | 10:30 | Break  |
Bob   |12:45  | 13:15 | Lunch  |
Bob   |15:00  | 15:15 | Break  |
Frank | 8:30  | 17:00 | Shift  |
Frank |10:30  | 10:45 | Break  |
Frank |12:00  | 12:30 | Lunch  |
Frank |15:15  | 15:30 | Break  |
```

I am looking for my query to return a whole shift breakdown:

```
Emp   | Start |  End  | Option | 
Bob   | 7:30  | 10:15 | Work   |
Bob   |10:15  | 10:30 | Break  |
Bob   |10:30  | 12:45 | Work   |
Bob   |12:45  | 13:15 | Lunch  |
Bob   |13:15  | 15:00 | Work   |
Bob   |15:00  | 15:15 | Break  |
Bob   |15:15  | 16:00 | Work   |
Frank | 8:30  | 10:30 | Work   |
Frank |10:30  | 10:45 | Break  |
Frank |10:45  | 12:00 | Work   |
Frank |12:00  | 12:30 | Lunch  |
Frank |12:30  | 15:15 | Work   |
Frank |15:15  | 15:30 | Break  |
Frank |15:30  | 17:00 | Work   |
```

I was thinking of using a case statement but I didn't know how to approach taking the shift and breaking it down across the remainder of the shift as work. Any help or recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more solution using a recursive CTE can look like this

```
WITH cte AS (    
    SELECT 
        s.emp,
        s.start,
        COALESCE((SELECT MIN(ss.start) FROM schedule ss WHERE ss.emp = s.emp AND ss.start > s.start), "end") AS "end",
        CAST('Work' AS VARCHAR(10)) AS "option",
        s."end" AS shift_end
    FROM schedule s
    WHERE s."option" = 'Shift'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        s.emp,
        s.start,
        COALESCE(s."end", cte.shift_end) AS "end",
        s."option",
        cte.shift_end
    FROM schedule s
    JOIN cte ON cte.emp = s.emp AND cte."end" <= s.start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        s.emp,
        s."end" AS start,
        COALESCE(LEAD(s.start) OVER (PARTITION BY s.emp ORDER BY s.start), cte.shift_end) AS "end",
        CAST('Work' AS VARCHAR(10)) AS "option",
        cte.shift_end
    FROM schedule s
    JOIN cte ON cte.emp = s.emp AND cte."end" <= s.start
)    
SELECT DISTINCT emp, start, "end", "option" FROM cte
ORDER BY emp, start
```

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b4421b52f07fe0ba777e7abd5549dc3)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that's a little more terse.  It can accommodate any number of breaks, and you can define additional break types if you want.  I think the only assumption is that work always follows a break, but that could probably be adjusted if need be.

```
BEGIN
declare @temp table (emp varchar(10),t1 time, t2 time, opt varchar(10))
declare @index table (optval varchar(10),eval int,shiftname varchar(10))
insert into @temp values  --this is your original data
('Bob','7:30','16:00','Shift'),
('Bob','10:15','10:30','Break'),
('Bob','12:45','13:15','Lunch'),
('Bob','15:00','15:15','Break'),
('Frank','8:30','17:00','Shift'),
('Frank','10:30','10:45','Break'),
('Frank','12:00','12:30','Lunch'),
('Frank','15:15','15:30','Break')
insert into @index values  --auxiliary definitions
('Break',0,'Work'),
('Break',1,'Break'),
('Lunch',0,'Work'),
('Lunch',1,'Lunch'),
('Shift',0,'error'),
('Shift',1,'Work')

select aa.emp,aa.s,aa.t1,aa.shiftname from
(select a.*,lag(a.t1,1) over(partition by emp order by a.emp,a.t1) as s,i.shiftname  from
((select emp,t1,opt,0 as e from @temp)
union all
(select emp,t2,opt,1 as e from @temp)) a
left join @index i on i.optval=a.opt and i.eval=a.e
) aa
where aa.s is not null
order by aa.emp,aa.s
END
```

And the results:

| emp | start_time | end_time | shiftname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 07:30:00 | 10:15:00 | Work |
| Bob | 10:15:00 | 10:30:00 | Break |
| Bob | 10:30:00 | 12:45:00 | Work |
| Bob | 12:45:00 | 13:15:00 | Lunch |
| Bob | 13:15:00 | 15:00:00 | Work |
| Bob | 15:00:00 | 15:15:00 | Break |
| Bob | 15:15:00 | 16:00:00 | Work |
| Frank | 08:30:00 | 10:30:00 | Work |
| Frank | 10:30:00 | 10:45:00 | Break |
| Frank | 10:45:00 | 12:00:00 | Work |
| Frank | 12:00:00 | 12:30:00 | Lunch |
| Frank | 12:30:00 | 15:15:00 | Work |
| Frank | 15:15:00 | 15:30:00 | Break |
| Frank | 15:30:00 | 17:00:00 | Work |

Thanks for reading, let me know if you want additional commentary!

Answer (score 0):

So, let's do this with the following caveats:

1. Your table layout is precisely how you indicated at the top where you have four rows per person.
2. Each person has a pattern of WORK-BREAK-WORK-LUNCH-WORK-BREAK-WORK.

You can use a combination of CTE's with some UNIONed queries such as this. I changed a few column names because they are reserved words (start, end, option).

```
  with breaks as (
  select emp, c_start, c_end, rank() over (partition by emp order by c_start asc) as b_rank
  from my_table
  where category = 'Break'
  ), 
  lunch as (
  select emp, c_start, c_end
  from my_table
  where category = 'Lunch'
  ), 
  shift as (
  select emp, c_start, c_end
  from my_table
  where category = 'Shift'
  )
  select distinct t.emp, s.c_start as c_start, b.c_start as c_end, 'Work' as category
    from my_table t 
    join breaks b on t.emp = b.emp 
    join shift s on t.emp = s.emp 
   where b.b_rank = 1
  union
  select distinct t.emp, b.c_start as c_start, b.c_end as c_end, 'Break' as category
    from my_table t 
    join breaks b on t.emp = b.emp 
   where b.b_rank = 1
  union
  select distinct t.emp, b.c_end as c_start, l.c_start as c_end, 'Work' as category
    from my_table t 
    join breaks b on t.emp = b.emp 
    join lunch l on t.emp = l.emp
   where b.b_rank = 1
  union
  select distinct t.emp, l.c_start as c_start, l.c_end as c_end, 'Lunch' as category
    from my_table t 
    join lunch l on t.emp = l.emp
  union
  select distinct t.emp, l.c_end as c_start, b.c_start as c_end, 'Work' as category
    from my_table t 
    join lunch l on t.emp = l.emp
    join breaks b on t.emp = b.emp
   where b.b_rank = 2
  union
  select distinct t.emp, b.c_start as c_start, b.c_end as c_end, 'Break' as category
    from my_table t 
    join breaks b on t.emp = b.emp
   where b.b_rank = 2
  union
  select distinct t.emp, b.c_end as c_start, s.c_end as c_end, 'Work' as category
    from my_table t 
    join breaks b on t.emp = b.emp
    join shift s on t.emp = s.emp
   where b.b_rank = 2
  order by 1,2
```

Output:

| emp | c_start | c_end | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 07:30:00 | 10:15:00 | Work |
| Bob | 10:15:00 | 10:30:00 | Break |
| Bob | 10:30:00 | 12:45:00 | Work |
| Bob | 12:45:00 | 13:15:00 | Lunch |
| Bob | 13:15:00 | 15:00:00 | Work |
| Bob | 15:00:00 | 15:15:00 | Break |
| Bob | 15:15:00 | 16:00:00 | Work |
| Frank | 08:30:00 | 10:30:00 | Work |
| Frank | 10:30:00 | 10:45:00 | Break |
| Frank | 10:45:00 | 12:00:00 | Work |
| Frank | 12:00:00 | 12:30:00 | Lunch |
| Frank | 12:30:00 | 15:15:00 | Work |
| Frank | 15:15:00 | 15:30:00 | Break |
| Frank | 15:30:00 | 17:00:00 | Work |

Db-fiddle can be found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gf1kh6YFbzAPYVmXxxS5zP/2).